# Get ProgressBar object from ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

Is there any way I can get the "mProgress" object from the ProgressDialog.java class?

I want to set the colour of an indeterminate spinner to white and keep the same android style for it. I've seen solutions using styling but none have really fit the criteria. I want everything to be exactly the same with it, just the colour to be white.

The reason I want the mProgress object is so I can use the below code on it:

```
mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, 0xFFFFFF));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
AlertDialog alert = progress; // not sure if you need this bit, required for what I do 

ProgressBar prog = (ProgressBar)progress.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
prog.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, 0xFFFFFF));
```